# Names of room-owning moderators should be italicized

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

This man is both a [moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6) (congratulations!) and one of the owners of ['Python' chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/), and this is how his name is displayed there

[image]

Names of moderators are blue, names of ROs are italicized, thus the names of moderators owning a chat room should be displayed (in that particular chat room) like this

[image]

Comment: Sixth room and sixth election: coincidence? I think not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So does that mean C# gets a mod next year? :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET that's the only possible conclusion!

Comment: IIRC moderator privileges trump room owner privileges, so there's not much point in showing both statuses.

Comment: @AdamLear is just appending `.owner` class :(

Comment: The current code must be something like `if (moderator) { cls += " moderator"; } else if (owner) { cls += " owner"; }` -> just remove the `else`.

Comment: And I guess this is of utmost importance - had Martijn known that his name not be in italics in room 6, it could very well have been that he'd not have run for moderator ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala [deobfuscated](http://pastebin.com/rx5d6THN)

Comment: Achso, thus: just remove `&& !cssClass`

Answer (score 3):

I've marked this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), even though there is an equally strong argument for marking it as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Either way, the system has changed in a way that obsoletes this feature request.

Now, **moderators' names in a chat room are shown in blue *and* italics**. Room owners' names continue to be shown in italic. Thus, the system has been changed to reflect what Adam Lear described in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291025/names-of-room-owning-moderators-should-be-italicized#comment180450_291025):

> moderator privileges trump room owner privileges, so there's not much point in showing both statuses.

Moderators are effectively room owners in all chat rooms on the site where they are moderators, so they are always shown with their names in italics (as well as in blue, to denote that they are moderators).

Comment: I don't really see this as "completed". The base request seems to be "please visually distinguish between moderators who are also room owners and moderators who are not room owners for this room". While the display did change to have *all* moderator names shown in italics, that still doesn't accomplish the underlying request here of visually distinguishing between moderators who are room owners and moderators who are not room owners.

Comment: Being able to distinguish between those two statuses does matter to regular users in some rooms. For some rooms, users are asked to ping a room owner to perform some tasks. While a moderator *can*, of course, perform those tasks, the specific moderator hasn't signed up to take care of such room actions (e.g. move a message into a specifically designated other room) just because they happen to be a moderator and in the room. In some rooms, regular users are explicitly enjoined against pinging moderators for such tasks.

Comment: That is a highly unique room culture that is not at all consistent with what Stack Exchange envisioned for the role of room owners, @Makyen. It is essentially elevating inherent limitations of the chat system (the inability of room owners to effectively moderate content) to a feature, where room owners *have* to do that moderation of content (and diamond moderators have to moderate content in the limited way that ROs can moderate content). That may be desirable in one specific case, but really doesn't make sense *in general* for chat rooms on SO or SE.